# After setting up ssh-keys, how can I ssh into the server such that the key-pair will be ignored?

Tags: ssh, scp, ssh-keygen

I have key-pairs to ssh and scp into a server without entering my password. There are numerous tutorials on this, e.g.

https://alvinalexander.com/linux-unix/how-use-scp-without-password-backups-copy

I would like to now set up an environment whereby this key-pair doesn't exist for some debugging. I don't want to delete they key-pair I already have though, because that's a pain. It's requires much deleting/resetting of keys in `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`, of which I have many.

Is it possible to ssh into the server in such a way such that the key-pair will be ignored? Is there a convenient way to enter in a "blank slate"  for debugging connection issues?

Comment: Any user that doesn't have a private key that corresponds to the public key(s) in the target machine's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file should be prompted for regular password authentication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can turn off public key authentication on a per-connection basis (and also disable connection sharing so that the new session does not connect over an already established one) via:

```
$ ssh -o ControlPath=none -o PubkeyAuthentication=no serverhost
```